# Installing kubectl

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl

Iam getting a message as `No package kubectl available` while installing kubectl

I have followed the documentation mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) 
for `CentOS VERSION="7 (Core)"` , Linux kernel version = 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x8

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg 
     https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
yum search kubectl
yum install -y kubectl
```

when it is executing the command `yum search kubectl` it is giving the following logs

```
yum -y search kubectl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
* base: mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu
* epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
* extras: centos-distro.1gservers.com
* updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Importing GPG key 0x.......(some value):
Userid     : "Google Cloud Packages RPM Signing Key <gc-team@google.com>"
Fingerprint:  xxxx xxxx ... (some value)
From       : https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
=============================== Matched: kubectl ===============================
kubernetes-client.x86_64 : Kubernetes client tools
$ yum install -y kubectl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu
* epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
* extras: centos-distro.1gservers.com
* updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
No package kubectl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I think it is not retrieving the key from "https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg"

Comment: Can you provide your CentOS version, and your Linux kernel version? These can be found using, `cat /etc/centos-release`; and `uname -a`. Please include in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally it should work with kubernetes.repo file also but it didn't work in my case. So installed using below steps from the official documentation and it was successful.

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Answer (score 0):

The package is clearly available from that repository, so we just need to check your configuration to make sure we can install it.

```xml
<package pkgid="3d5dd3e6a783afcd660f9954dec3999efa7e498cac2c14d63725fafa1b264f14" name="kubectl" arch="x86_64"><version epoch="0" ver="1.15.0" rel="0"/><file>/usr/bin/kubectl</file></package>
```

Source: https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/filelists.xml

I would first check that A)`/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo` actually exists, and B) that the contents match, i.e., via `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo`.

Next, both of the commands below can be used to search for the `kubectl` package.

```sh
# Using search
yum search kubectl

# Using grep
yum list | grep kubectl
```

For importing the GPG key for use with `yum`, see the following answer:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337257/247886

Comment: Hi I have updated the question, please check and suggest some solutions . Thanks !
I have tried making gpgcheck=0  repo_gpgcheck=0 .. but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with this:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
setenforce 0
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

2. You may also try to install a specific version by executing: `yum install -y kubelet-<version> kubectl-<version> kubeadm-<version>`
3. Always make sure your versions satisfy [dependency requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin).
4. If you have some older versions, uninstall them first.
5. You may also consider using [kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Please let me know if that helped.